# Cancel ToolStripDropDownButton dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstripdropdown

I need to programmatically cancel the dropdown of a ToolStripDropDownButton in the DropDownOpening event. However I cannot figure out a way to achieve this.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you cannot disable the button when the operation is not valid?

Comment: Which is indeed the best way, there's no support for canceling it.

Answer (score 0):

You can either do nothing in the opening event, or disable the control so I can't be interacted with to even generate the opening event:

```
toolStripDropDownButton.Enabled = false
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.enabled